# FME geometry conversion from string?

Tags: geometry, fme-form, excel, geometry-conversion, string

I have an xlsx file that has incorrect X, Y location. Essentially the false northing is out 5000000 and there's no decimal point. As you can see in the image below the current file format is on the left and format I need it in is on the right.

[image]

I can use the following FMW workflow to get the correct coordinates and export to xlsx without issue.

[image]

However, when I try to reproject the coordinates within the same workflow I can't get it to work?

This is what I'm trying to do

[image]

When I open up the exported xlsx I get the same coordinates? (like no reprojection has happened?) Any ideas what I'm missing?

(on a side note, if I open up the exported xlsx file in a new workbench and run the reprojector it works perfectly)

Answer (score 4):

Your reprojected features are not being written. The excel writer is likely writing attributes only. 
After the reprojector try adding a [coordinateextractor](https://docs.safe.com/fme/2018.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/coordinateextractor.htm) to populate attributes with the point lat/long and this should let the writer do its stuff.

Comment: That's done the trick Jim. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: If this reply answered your question, please accept it as per the site guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd recommend using an ExpressionEvaluator or AttributeManager to calculate the correct coordinates instead of using StringReplacers. e.g. @Value(Y) / 1000 + 5000000
Second, since you're writing out to Excel, just use an AttributeReprojector instead of the VertexCreator and Reprojector.  Are you writing out to a new Excel file?

Comment: I will check it out Dan, I haven't been convinced about the string replace transformer, It was just something I could do quickly. Eventually, I will be posting into AGOL but I was just trying to get the reprojection happening first!